# Problema servidor js

Tags: nodejs, facebook, servidor

Tengo un problema para crear un servidor con node JS. Escribo este codigo

```
//Importando
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');

//Instancia 
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Puerto en el cual se encuentra el servidor 
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("El servidor se encuentra en el puerto 3000");
});

//Configuramos primera ruta con parametros request y response
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Bienvenido al taller');
});
```

Y cmd desplega esto:

```
C:\Proyects\Taller_Bot\node_modules>node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Proyects\Taller_Bot\node_modules\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo pude resolver, error de novato, carpeta erronea

solo escribí

```
cd ../ 
node index.js
```

y funcionó